# JQuery .click() event, very odd behavior in IE 8&9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, event-handling, event-bubbling

I've created a video gallery which loads a Youtube video via swfobject, based on the element's data attributes. It functions quite well in all browsers, except IE. The strange behavior I am seeing doesn't make sense.

The markup for each thumbnail is as follows:

```
<li>
    <div class="movie-image">
        <a class="" data-videotitle="Title" data-videoid="$node.contribution('video')" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=41ZskpgQqZ4">
            <img class="video-link" data-videotitle="Title" data-videoid="41ZskpgQqZ4" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/41ZskpgQqZ4/default.jpg" alt="Title">
            <h5>Title</h5>
        </a>
    </div>
</li>
```

With this javascript binding the event:

```
$('.video-link').click(function(){
    player.setVideo(this.getAttribute("data-videoid"), true);
    player.setTitle(this.getAttribute("data-videotitle"));
    window.event.returnValue = false; //IESUX
    if(window.event.stopPropagation) window.event.stopPropagation();
    window.event.cancelBubble = true;
    //Yes, there's a lot of redundancy here. None has worked.
    return false;
})
```

**Now, here's the weird part:** When I click a link in any browser except IE, the event works fine.

However, in IE, if I click on the h5 element, everything works fine. If I click on the image, however, the browser navigates to the thumbnail. Which is really odd, since that's not even the target of the link.

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention, I am stuck using JQuery 1.4.2 on this particular webpage.

**Edit 2:** Well... crap. I just tried putting together a fiddle to show the problem, but the fiddle is working fine, even with the old version of JQuery.

Comment: Just looking at your code and markup, when you click on the h5 element, it should be navigating to the video in all browsers. Nothing you do should be navigating to the thumbnail.

Comment: I know... that's why it's so weird.

Comment: This is a little nitpicky, but I'd think clicking the h5 shouldn't do anything at all inside the click handler. Or if the event does bubble up, it should cause an error since the h5 doesn't have any data attributes. Are you sure `this` inside your anonymous function refers to what you think it does?

Comment: In JS, the `click` event will propogate all the way up until it finds an event listener (and then even up beyond that unless you explicitly stop the bubble), so, yes, the click function was firing with the div as the target.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery wraps the event object and gives it methods that do what you're trying to do only better:

```
$(".video-link").click(function (e) {
   player.setVideo(this.getAttribute("data-videoid"), true);
   player.setTitle(this.getAttribute("data-videotitle"));
   e.stopPropagation();
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Note that `return false` is explicitly left out -- you don't need it.

My guess is that IE is either throwing some sort of error that stops the JS execution and ends up following the link, or the default action is not properly being stopped.

Comment: The strange thing is that `return false` would automatically do stopPropagation and preventDefault. hmm

Comment: As I just noted in my edit, I'm stuck using JQuery 1.4.2 in this... maybe that's why returning false isn't doing the trick? I'll be trying this in a minute and letting you know how it goes.

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS what I'm suggesting as a possibility is that `return false` does not get reached because of an error beforehand, but I guess my suggestion doesn't fix it.  Do you know whether the click event gets triggered at all in IE?

Comment: Yes, the click function is triggered and is executed fully before going haywire. I'm thinking I might have a conflict with another script running on the page, because I tried making a minimal JSFiddle, and it was working fine, even with the old version of JQuery. Also, it does not appear to be an issue with the default action happening, because the target of the link is different from where the browser ends up.

Comment: I voted you up because under normal circumstances, this answer would have been very helpful, and likely would have fixed the issue. However, this turned out to be a weird problem with the old version of JQuery, IE, and perhaps another script that was running. I got rid of the anchor tag, and it appears to be working now.